# Выбрасывание исключения в блоке Catch (Java)

Tags: java, исключения, try-catch

Есть проблемка: при возникновении исключения **IOException** нужно его обработать и в блоке ***Catch*** выбросить моё исключение **ServerRunningException**, которое будет обрабатываться при вызове метода извне, при помощи **throws** в сигнатуре. Но IDE требует от меня принудительного обрабатывания, что меня не устраивает...

---

Сэмплы кода:

*(Метод)*

```
public boolean connect() throws ServerRunningException {  //Перебросил вверх по иерархии
  Thread processing = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        ExecutorService flowsPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(COUNT_OF_CONNECTIONS);
        Semaphore block = new Semaphore(COUNT_OF_CONNECTIONS);

        while (true) {
            block.acquire();

            Socket accept = server.accept();
            flowsPool.execute(() -> {
                try (
                    InputStream inputStream = accept.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "cp1251"));
                    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
                ){
                    String command;
                    do {
                    command = br.readLine();
                        Validation.check(command);
                    } while(command != null);
                    accept.close();
                    System.out.println("closed ..");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NullPointerException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    block.release();
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new ServerRunningException(ex); //unreported exception ServerRunningException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    }
});
processing.start();
return true;
}
```

*(Класс собственного исключения)*

```
public class ServerRunningException extends IOException{
  String message;

  public ServerRunningException(Throwable ex){
    message = ex.getMessage();
    initCause(ex);
  }

  @Override
  public String getMessage(){
    return message;
  }
}
```

---

*Заранее спасибо)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не IDE требует а java компилятор.

В качестве решения Вы можете наследовать Ваше исключение от [java.lang.RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), наследников этого исключения не надо объявлять в сигнатурах методов, т.н. [unchecked exceptions](https://habr.com/ru/company/golovachcourses/blog/225585/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. С блока Catch никак не перебросишь наверх, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Dev0ps я не понял про наверх

Comment: Имею в виду, вместо обработки (try-catch) в текущем блоке кода, указать throws в сигнатуре метода и обрабатывать уже в месте вызова...

Comment: @Dev0ps можно, но сложно [тык](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-exceptions)